# Where have these Git conflicts come from?

Tags: git

I just don't get it. I have a branch `production` and a branch `master`. Been working on production for ages when maybe I should have been merging with master more often.

`production's` last commit was a few hours ago is, `master's` was weeks ago.

I run

`git checkout master`

`git merge production`

and I have about 10 conflicts. 20 files that "need merge."

I don't get it. It's only me working on this project, why am I getting this conflict?

I thought a conflict arose when two developers edited the same code at the same time? The code in my `production` branch is obviously the code I want. So odd. I've been merging into the master quite happily and then suddenly this.

Comment: It's not necessarily two developers editing the same code. It's code that has changed in two places. If you changed a line of code in master and in production, that will cause a conflict because Git doesn't know what you want to keep.

Answer (score 0):

The reason for merge conflicts is that the information in the conflicting files have diverged. When you are to merge the files they have a common 'base' version, an 'ours' version which is the version you are standing at, and a 'theirs' version that is the version from the branch that you want to merge from.

If your are really sure that it is the code in the production branch you want I think this will solve your problem. Standing in master:

```
$ git merge -s theirs production
```

An alternative is to run the mergetool and choose the correct changes by hand.

```
$ git mergetool
```